# Why is it trivial for compact Riemann surfaces to have a countable topology?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

In "Lectures on Riemann surfaces" by Otto Forster, before the proof of Rado's theorem which asserts that every Riemann surface has a countable topology,
the author commented "Clearly this is trivial for compact Riemann surfaces".
This is not clear at all for me. Could someone help me understand this ?

Comment: Riemann surfaces do not have countable topologies. Do you mean second countable?

Comment: @Aki: You mean "has a **countable base for its topology**", a.k.a. is second-countable. This is a much weaker condition than "has a countable topology".

Comment: What is "countable topology"? Does it mean that it has a topology which is first or second countable?

Comment: Thank you @ChrisEagle and ZevChonoles for quick answers. The above is the direct quotation from the book. I understand it as second countable or "has a countable base for its topology" as you suspect.

Answer (score 6):

Such a surface is a union of finitely many open disks. Each disk has a countable basis consisting of balls of rational radius around points with rational coordinates. The union of the bases for each disk is a countable basis for the whole space.

Comment: Thank you ! Now it is clear for me too.